# Show a loading spinner while a fragment is loading

Tags: android, android-fragments, loading

I have developed a fragment-based app.

I have a menu fragment with buttons,these buttons open a new fragment each one, replacing the last one.

The issue is, that some fragment takes a while in opening cause it does some calls to asynctasks and populates some listviews.

So when I press the button in the menu fragment, it keeps freezed 2 seconds     until the new fragment appears replacing the menu fragment.

I would like that a spinner or "loading.." dialog appears in that time.

I have tested this

```
        private progressDialog progressDialog;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.show();
```

This code show the dialog but it never shows it when the screen is freezed.

Where I should place that code? in the activity which contains all fragments or in the menu fragment? or maybe in the fragment which is loaded?

I dont get to accomplish this so when in my menu fragment I press the button I do the following code.

```
         NewAppointmentFragment fragment = new NewAppointmentFragment();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =

        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, 
        "NewAppointmentFragment");
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

but it takes 2 seconds until this new fragment is loaded and appears
The  freezed 2 seconds you can see the menu fragment with the button pressed

**Could be cause in the new fragment I call all the asynctasks and operations to populate listviews in  OnCreateView ?**

How could I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

My menu fragment

```
      @Override
         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


         nextAppointmentsButton = (Button) 
         rootView.findViewById(R.id.nextAppointmentsButton);
         nuevaCitaButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nuevaCitaButton);
         nearbyPharmaciesButton = (Button) 
         rootView.findViewById(R.id.nearbyPharmaciesButton);
         ourLocationButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ourLocationButton);

         nextAppointmentsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                UpcomingAppointmentsFragment fragment = new 
         UpcomingAppointmentsFragment();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =

          getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }

         });

         nuevaCitaButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 ((MainActivity)getActivity()).showProgressDialog();
                 NewAppointmentFragment fragment = new NewAppointmentFragment();
                 android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =

         getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, 
         "NewAppointmentFragment");
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }

        });

        nearbyPharmaciesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NearbyPharmaciesFragment fragment = new NearbyPharmaciesFragment();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =

        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }

        });
        ourLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                OurLocationMapFragment fragment = new OurLocationMapFragment();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =

        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }

        });


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
        }
```

My new Fragment loaded when I press the menu button

```
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_appointment, 
        container, false);

      // **Calls to asynctasks **
      // **Populate operations ListViews**

      return rootView;
      }
```

Comment: Show the "**Calls to asynctasks**" - sounds you're doing something wrong and blocking the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you put a ProgressBar widget inside your layout:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Then in your fragment:

```
ProgressBar mProgressBar;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
 mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
 //other references
 return view;
}
```

When you finish your http request:

```
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

mProgressDialog.setMessage("Working ...");

private void doSomeWorkMethod() {

mProgressDialog.show();

doSomeWork . . .

mProgressDialog.dismiss();

Snackbar.make(v, "Work Complete.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
  .setAction("Action", null).show();
}
```

Comment: `ProgressDialog` has been officially depreciated by the Android team. An implementation of `ProgressBar` (or something similar) inside an Activity is now recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow these steps your UI should not freeze:

1. Load the new fragment
2. Start Async task
3. Initialize `Progressdialog` in constructor of `AsyncTask` where you want to load the data
4. Show `Progressdialog` in `onPreExecute()` in your `AsyncTask` with `dialog.show()`
5. Dismiss the `Progressdialog` in `onPostExecute()` in your `AsyncTask` with `dialog.dismiss()`
6. Update the UI / set the new data to your adapter etc.

Comment: I have several fragments loading, and this shows all progress dialogs overlapping in one activity, can I bind progress to fragment only?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably doing long running tasks which blocks the UI thread.
First thing you have to do is switch to Kotlin and then,

1. Create a viewmodel
2. Add a function in viewmodel which returns a flow

   fun doTask() = flow {
   val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
   // do your task here.
   // Below is an example code
   val myResult = 1 + 1
   myResult
   }
   emit(result)
   }
3. In fragment, create a scope like

   showProgress()
   viewLifeCycleOwner.lifeCycleScope.launch {
   viewModel.doTask().collectLatest { result ->
   hideProgress()
   }

   }