# Android Fragment display a loading while rendering layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Let's say I've got an `Activity` with only a `FrameLayout` (*I've also try with the new `FragmentContainerView`*) so I will be loading `Fragments` on it. Let's assume I've got two Fragments: **fragA** and **fragB**, I will first load **fragA** and with a button, present in that fragment, *replace* it with **fragB**.

I've define a function on my `Activity` so I can load a new `Fragment` on the container:

```java
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction fragTrans = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null);

    fragTrans.commit();
}
```

And I will call this from **fragA** to go to **fragB**. This far so good, everything works fine. Actually the problem I'm facing is not about functioning, is that I don't like the loading time of **fragB**, it takes about 2sec, and I'd like to display a loading to the user, but I'm not able to achieve it.

The first thing I've try is adding a **gone** `ProgressBar` to the activity layout, where the container is. Then my `loadFragment` function will first set this progressBar visible and then perform the fragment transaction and each fragment will hide (*gone*) this View before exiting the `onCreateView` method. But the problem is that the user never sees this `ProgressBar`, it's like the main UI is freezed while rendering the layout of the **fragB** and therefore does not update the UI making this progressBar usesless. I even see some **frame skipped** in the LogCat about 50 frames.

Both fragments have no logic just the `onCreateView` implemented where the layout is inflated. I can notice that if I change the layout of **fragB** to a simpler one it loads instantly, so I'm guessing the issue is related to the time it takes to render the layout. This *heavy* layout is a really big form with lots of `TextInputLayout` with `TextInputEditText` and `MaterialSpinner` (from GitHub).

I know I maybe can simplify the layout, but I'd like to know how can I display a loading while rendering. For example, I've seen some apps load some kind of *dummy-view* while loading and then replace it with real data.

One thing I've try is to load a **dummy** layout with a `ProgressBar` in the middle and in the `onCreateView` method post a `Handler` to inflate a **real** layout on the same container in the background, like this:

```java
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dummy, container, false);

    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            container.removeAllViews();
            View realView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_real, container);
        }
    });
}
```

This kinda work, as the viewing experience is nice, but when navigating back, the layout of **fragB** remains visible as background of the other fragments. I have not test it but maybe I can call `container.removeAllViews();` before exiting the fragment and it will work, but still seems like a workaround rather than a solution, to me.

And other thing I've not try because maybe is an over-kill is to have an **intermediate** or **loading** fragment and load it always before the real fragment, and I will pass an Intent Extra to it so I can tell what's the real fragment I want to display. This intermediate fragment will not be added to the backstack.

How do you solve this kind of problems?

Comment: I remember they call **Skeleton** view to the dummy view I was referencing in my post. And it will also be like **Shimmer** but as the problem is that the UI is frozen I can not update the UI

Comment: Add a static dialog object in application class (in which you can show progress) using activity or application context. Show before loading view and hide the same after loading.

Comment: @NileshB thanks for your proposal. I've try it with no luck, same thing as with the progressBar I talk about, it freezes and shows nothing. I thought maybe being static could help, but no. Right now the only working solution I've found is the one with the `Handler` and removing all views in the onDestroyView method. But seems ugly to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that `AsyncLayoutInflater` is the way to go!

Here's how I use it:

```java
private ViewGroup fragmentContainer;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View dummyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dummy_loading, container, false);

    fragmentContainer = container;
    AsyncLayoutInflater asyncLayoutInflater = new AsyncLayoutInflater(getContext());


    asyncLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_real_layout, container, new AsyncLayoutInflater.OnInflateFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInflateFinished(@NonNull View view, int resid, @Nullable ViewGroup parent) {
            fragmentContainer.removeAllViews();
            fragmentContainer.addView(view);
        }
    });


    return dummyView;
}


@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    fragmentContainer.removeAllViews();
}
```

Up there, **fragment_dummy_loading** is a layout with a `ProgressBar` and **fragment_real_layout** is the real heavy layout.

There's just one thing I don't get... and that's how can I bind Objects to the XML widgets *(**without using Android Data Binding, if possible**)* when the `AsyncLayoutInflater` fallsback to infalte in the UI thread.

According to the docs:

> If the layout that is trying to be inflated cannot be constructed asynchronously for whatever reason, AsyncLayoutInflater will automatically fall back to inflating on the UI thread.

And I check the source of `AsyncLayoutInflater` and I can tell that the method **onInflateFinished** is called no matter if the inflation was in the background or in the main thread

Comment: When i implement this error shows

views added to a fragmentcontainerview must be associated with a fragment. view androidx.constraintlayout.widget.constraintlayout

You have any solution?

Comment: Sorry @Ahmad I've never encounter that error. Maybe you can create a new question, post more details and send me the link so I can look at it

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use AsycTask when your new fragment loading

1- Load the new fragment

2 -Start Async task

3 - Initialize Progressdialog in constructor of AsyncTask where you want to load the data

4 - Show Progressdialog in onPreExecute() in your AsyncTask with dialog.show()

5 - Dismiss the Progressdialog in onPostExecute() in your AsyncTask with dialog.dismiss()

6- Update the UI / set the new data to your adapter etc

Check here 
[Show a loading spinner while a fragment is loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771296/show-a-loading-spinner-while-a-fragment-is-loading)

Comment: Thanks! I'd rather not use `AsyncTask` as they are (or going to be) deprecated: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: You are right. I mean that you have to use a background worker when your second fragment opening. Rx Java can be a good alternative. Or You can use Coroutines if you are using Kotlin. https://www.techyourchance.com/asynctask-deprecated/

Comment: Sadly I'm not into Kotlin (at least for now), and about the background worker, that's why I think about the `Handler`, because it's simplicity. So you too think that a background worker is the way to go? It seems odd that there's no off-the-shelve solution. I've been reading about `AsyncLayoutInflater` (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/asynclayoutinflater/view/AsyncLayoutInflater) but I don't know if it will help me

Comment: Well, the Handler seems not to work. I was testing it with a simple layout with a TextView that says loading and it was working, but when I change it to a ProgressBar I only see a blank screen. Again, the UI is frozen so it seems the progress bar con not be animated. And I'm guessing the same will happen with any background worker, because the inflation uses the UI thread, right?

Comment: I have just read your link. Thank you it is useful for me also. I see from your link AsyncLayoutInflater inflates your views asynchronously. This can be true for your case, however using RxJava also can be true. ı think you have try both of them.

Comment: inflation uses the UI. For this reason you have to use background thread for animating your progress. Decidedly try RxJava

Comment: But how can I make any animation with the UI frozen? That confuses me

Comment: I think these are going to be in different threads. So this is not a problem. However in your target fragment you have to check your views also. Why are they freezing while inflating. Maybe you have to do an optimization in your layout

Comment: Well AFAIK there's one and only one main/UI thread on Android... I'm testing with `AsyncLayoutInflater`, so far so good. The ProgressBar shows up and there's a callback when the view is done inflating. Now I'll have to see how to apply/display the inflated view because I'm only seeing the ProgressBar all the time